# Sudoku in C vs Sudoku in Java

Tags: java, c, reference, sudoku

I recently wrote a simple straightforward C code that solves Sudoku and that uses recursion and backtracking. You will find below the code that I just described. Everything works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
# define INsigned 0

int grid[9][9];
void printGrid(){
int row,col;

for(row=0;row<9;row++){
    for(col=0;col<9;col++){
        printf("%2d",grid[row][col]);
        }
    printf("\n");
        }   
}

int Unsigned(int *row, int* col){
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<9;i++){
    for(j=0;j<9;j++){

        if(grid[i][j]==0){
            *row=i;
            *col=j;
            return 1;


        }
    }

}
return 0;

}
int check(){
int row=0;
int col=0;
int i;
if(Unsigned(&row, &col)==0)
    return 1;


for(i=1;i<=9;i++){
    if(conflict(i,row-row%3, col-col%3, row, col)==0){

        grid[row][col]=i;
        if(check()==1)
            return 1;
    }


    grid[row][col]=0;
}

return 0;
}

int conflict (int num, int srow, int scol, int row, int col){

int i,j;
for(i=0;i<9;i++){
    if(grid[row][i]==num) return 1;
    if(grid[i][col]==num) return 2;
}

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        if(grid[i+srow][j+scol]==num) return 3;
    }
}
return 0;

}   

int main(){

int i;

for(i=0;i<9;i++){
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",&grid[i][0],&grid[i][1],&grid[i][2],
                                       &grid[i][3],&grid[i][4],&grid[i][5],
                                       &grid[i][6],&grid[i][7],&grid[i][8]);
}

check();
printf("\n\n");
printGrid();

}
```

The input is :

```
0 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 3
0 0 5 0 0 0 0 9 0
3 0 0 8 1 0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 4 3 1 0 0
5 6 0 0 9 0 0 7 8
0 0 3 5 6 0 0 0 0
9 0 6 0 8 7 0 0 4
0 2 0 0 0 0 8 0 0
1 0 0 9 0 0 0 0 0
```

So the problem that I have occurs when I tried to write the exact algorithm in java. Since java does not allow the pass by reference for primitive types and since I used the pass by reference in the **Unsigned function** that looks for the next empty cell. I decided to use a wrapper class in java in order to overcome this obstacle however the java equivalent of this code that not work as it should be Here is the code.

```
    public class intObj {

        public int value;
    }





public class Grid {

int grid[][] = new int[9][9];
int r = 0;
int c = 0;

public Grid(int grid[][]) {
    this.grid = grid;
}

void printGrid() {
    int row;
    int col;
    System.out.println("");
    for (row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d", grid[row][col]);
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
}

int conflict(int num, int srow, int scol, int row, int col) {

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (grid[row][i] == num) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (grid[i][col] == num) {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (grid[i + srow][j + scol] == num) {
                return 3;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}

int Unsigned(intObj row, intObj col) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] == 0) {

                row.value = i;
                col.value = j;
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}

int check() {

    intObj row = new intObj();
    intObj col = new intObj();

    if (Unsigned(row, col) == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (conflict(i, (row.value) - (row.value) % 3,
                (col.value) - (col.value) % 3, row.value, col.value) == 0) {


            grid[row.value][col.value] = i;
            if (check() == 1) {
                return 1;
            }

        }

        grid[row.value][col.value] = 0;
    }

    return 0;

}
}
```

The main class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int grid[][] = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 3},
        {0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 3},
        {3, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0},
        {5, 6, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 7, 8},
        {0, 0, 3, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {9, 0, 6, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 4},
        {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

    Grid g = new Grid(grid);


    g.check();

    g.printGrid();

}
}
```

Sorry for the long post any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: U could have used Integer class.

Comment: No. `Integer` can't be modified. He could have used `org.omg.CORBA.IntegerHolder`, though.

Comment: Integer Class is immutable in java

Comment: Have you tried debugging it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution that I can think of Is "Move your unsigned code inside check() itself"

```
int check(){
int row=0;
int col=0;
int i;
if(Unsigned(&row, &col)==0) //Move Unsigned() method code here and that's it
    return 1;
```

**II'nd Solution:** These two objects that you are creating in check() 
 method must be part of your Grid class,do not create them locally in check() method.It should resolve your problem

```
 intObj row = new intObj();
    intObj col = new intObj();
```